# What determines when a class object is destroyed in PHP?

Tags: php, class, destructor, instantiation

Let's say that we have class `CFoo`.  In the following example when is `CFoo::__destruct()` called?

```
function MyPHPFunc()
{
  $foo = new CFoo();

  . . .

  // When/where/how does $foo get destroyed/deleted?
}
```

In this example would the destructor be called when the script exits the scope of `MyPHPFunc` because `$foo` would no longer be accessible?

Comment: When the script is being terminated (during shutdown sequence).

Comment: go to the source first: the php manual.. quote: "The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence" so when you no longer use it or the script ends/it is killed. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In PHP all values are saved in so called `zval`s. Those `zval`s contain the actual data, type information and - this is important for your question - a reference count. Have a look at the following snippet:

```
$a = new B; // $a         points to zval(new B) with refcount=1
$b = $a;    // $a, $b     point to  zval(new B) with refcount=2 (+1)
$c = $b;    // $a, $b, $c point to  zval(new B) with refcount=3 (+1)
unset($a);  //     $b, $c point to  zval(new B) with refcount=2 (-1)
```

As soon as the `refcount` reaches `0` the `zval` is freed and the object destructor is called.

Here are some examples of the `refcount` reaching `0`:

- `unset`ing a variable:

  ```
  $a = new B; // refcount=1
  unset($a);  // refcount=0 => __destruct!
  ```

  But:

  ```
  $a = new B; // refcount=1
  $b = $a;    // refcount=2
  unset($a);  // refcount=1 => no destruct as refcount > 0, even though unset() was called!
  ```
- leaving function (or method) scope

  ```
  function a() {
      $a = new B; // refcount=1
  }               // refcount=0 => __destruct! (as $a does not exist anymore)
  ```
- script execution end

  ```
  $a = new B; // refcount=1
  die();      // refcount=0 => __destruct! (on script execution end all vars are freed)
  // doesn't need to be die(), can be just normal execution end
  ```

These obviously are not all conditions leading to a reduction of `refcount`, but the ones you will most commonly meet.

Also I should mention that since PHP 5.3 circular references will be detected, too. So if object `$a` references object `$b` and `$b` references `$a` and there aren't any further references to `$a` or `$b` the `refcount`s of both will be `1`, but they still will be freed (and `__destruct`ed). In this case though the order of destruction is undefined behavior.

Comment: Also note when using things like at-runtime user created functions (create_function) or running code inside an eval statement the garbage collection can get a little funny. For instance: If you declare a class and thus also its methods (with a destructor) inside an eval statement, then create a global instance of that class. You will notice that the destructor never gets called! Thats because when the destructor method would be called, it was already picked up by garbage collection after the eval exited, so the function no longer exists. (this might be an undocumented bug)

Comment: Well what i did was create_function(eval('class someclass{__desstructor(){some code}} global $a; $a=new someclass();')) Something like that...

Comment: @NikiC, can you elaborate more on the GC part in the answer?

Comment: So, `$a = new B; $a = new B;` would see the first instance of `B` destruct upon the second assignment of `$a`? Or does it destruct when GC runs/script ends?

Comment: @crush It will destruct on the second assignment of $a.

Comment: How does destruction work in the presence of [exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7470969/596781)?

Answer (score 4):

> PHP 5 introduces a destructor concept similar to that of other
>   object-oriented languages, such as C++. The destructor method will be
>   called as soon as there are no other references to a particular
>   object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.
>   - [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

If you want to see the process in action, [you can run this code here](http://codepad.org/os8qP6ml).

```
<?php

class A
{
    public function __construct() { var_dump('Creating: '. get_class($this)); }
    public function __destruct() { var_dump('Removing: '. get_class($this)); }
}

class B extends A {}

$A = new A();

/*
 * When this block is called later on
 */
function create_b()
{
    $B = new B();
} // At this point the function scope ends, and since $B is not referenced anymore it's removed.


var_dump('B is next');
create_b(); // Run above block, create, then destroy be
var_dump('B is now gone');

// At this point the PHP file parser ends, $A is destroyed since it's not used anymore
```

Answer (score 2):

The information is in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), albeit somewhat cryptic:

> PHP 5 introduces a destructor concept similar to that of other object-oriented languages, such as C++. The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.

Meaning: The destructor will be called when the object gets destroyed (= e.g. `unset()`), or when the script shuts down.

Additional useful info:

> Like constructors, parent destructors will not be called implicitly by the engine. In order to run a parent destructor, one would have to explicitly call parent::__destruct() in the destructor body.
>
> The destructor will be called even if script execution is stopped using exit(). Calling exit() in a destructor will prevent the remaining shutdown routines from executing.

Comment: So, in the case of my example would the destructor be called when the script exits the scope of `MyPHPFunc` because `$foo` would no longer be accessible?

Comment: @Jim that is a good question, and the answer is - I don't know! (You should however write `function` in front of your code so it's clear what you're asking.) My *guess* would be that it will be destroyed at the end of the function - one would have to try out. I'm tempted to remove this answer because it doesn't answer what you ask

Answer (score 1):

the best way to know is to test.

however the simple answer is that __destruct is called during garbage cleanup. coarse that does not help anyone as garbage cleanup is an ongoing process that cleans up local variables when there is no scope that can call them.

however here is some sample code, and the result which fully explains what happens when exiting scope internally to the script.

```
<?php
class testingdestructor {
    public function __construct($num) {
        $this->num = $num;
    }
    public function __destruct() {
        echo "I am number {$this->num}\n";
    }
}
class testing2{
    public function __construct($num) {
        $this->classtest = new testingdestructor($num);
    }
    public function __destruct() {
        echo "I am not a number\n";
    }
}
$iam1 = new testingdestructor(1);
$iam4 = new testing2(4);
function testfunction() {
    $iam2 = new testingdestructor(2);
}
testfunction();
$iam3 = new testingdestructor(3);
unset($iam1);
```

the output of this strange set of classes function and vars is this

```
I am number 2
I am number 1
I am number 3
I am not a number
I am number 4
```

this shows us that the end of the function calls the __destruct, as does unset, and that at least in practice that end of script cleanup is done in reverse order created.

Answer (score 0):

if create instance of a class and use the object.after finishing all your tasks  if u call the destructor and again use the same object in the next line to perform some other task u will be no longer able to use. That means ur destructor is called successfully