# __destruct() and __call() create endless loop

Tags: php, oop, methods, closures, destructor

I simplified my code a lot, but what I am doing is something like this:

```
class App{

    protected $apps = [];

    public function __construct($name, $dependencies){
        $this->name = $name;

        $apps = [];
        foreach($dependencies as $dependName){
            $apps[$name] = $dependName($this); // returns an instance of App
        }
        $this->apps = $apps;
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        foreach($this->apps as $dep){
            $result = $dep->cleanup($this);
        }
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments){
        if(is_callable([$this, $name])){
            return call_user_func_array([$this, $name], $arguments);
        }
    }
}


function PredefinedApp(){
    $app = new App('PredefinedApp', []);

    $app->cleanup = function($parent){
        // Do some stuff
    };
    return $app;
}
```

I then create an app like this:

```
$app = new App('App1', ['PredefinedApp']);
```

It creates an `App` instance, and then the items in the array create new app instances of whatever is defined and place them into an internal app array.

When I execute my destructor on the main app, it should call `cleanup()` on all the child apps. But what is happening, is that it is executing an endless loop, and I am not sure why.

I do notice that if I comment out `call_user_func_array` then `__call()` is only called once, but it doesn't execute the actual `closure` then.

I have also noticed, that if I do a `var_dump()` in the `__call()` it dumps endlessly. If I do a `var_dump()` in `cleanup()` instead I get a `http 502` error.

Comment: @RyanVincent if you put all the code into a file, and run the file you should see the issue

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is caused by you overloading `__call()` then using `call_user_func_array()`... which calls `__call()` again. Forever. Or at least until you run out of memory.

Comment: I'm debugging it atm and, i think that the __desctruct() is causing all this. Since if I remove it everything works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let us go through the code and look what happens here and why:

```js
01|    class App{ 
02|
03|        protected $apps = [];
04|
05|        public function __construct($name, $dependencies){
06|            $this->name = $name;
07|
08|            $apps = [];
09|            foreach($dependencies as $dependName){
10|                $apps[$name] = $dependName($this);
11|            }
12|            $this->apps = $apps;
13|        }
14|
15|        public function __destruct(){
16|            foreach($this->apps as $dep){
17|                $result = $dep->cleanup($this);
18|            }
19|        }
20|
21|        public function __call($name, $arguments){
22|            if(is_callable([$this, $name])){
23|                return call_user_func_array([$this, $name], $arguments);
24|            }
25|        }
26|    }
27| 
28|    function PredefinedApp(){
29|        $app = new App('PredefinedApp', []);
30|
31|        $app->cleanup = function($parent){
32|            //Do stuff like: echo "I'm saved";
33|        };
34|        return $app;
35|    }
36|  
37|    $app = new App('App1', ['PredefinedApp']);
```

<sub>**Note:** Line numbers added for each line of the code, so I can reference to these lines in the answer below</sub>

## Problem

1. You create an instance of: `App` with the following line:

   ```
   $app = new App('App1', ['PredefinedApp']);  //Line: 37
   ```
2. The constructor gets called:

   ```
   public function __construct($name, $dependencies){ /* Code here */ }  //Line: 05
   ```

   2.1. Following parameters are passed:

   - `$name` = `"App1"`
   - `$dependencies` = `["PredefinedApp"]`
3. You assign `$name` to `$this->name` with this line:

   ```
   $this->name = $name;  //Line: 06
   ```
4. You initialize `$apps` with an empty array:

   ```
   $apps = [];  //Line: 08
   ```
5. Now you loop through each element of `$dependencies`, which has 1 element here (`["PredefinedApp"]`)
6. In the loop you do the following:

   6.1 Assign the return value of a function call to an array index:

   ```
   $apps[$name] = $dependName($this);  //Line: 10
   //$apps["App1"] = PredefinedApp($this);
   ```
7. You call the function:

   ```
   PredefinedApp(){ /* Code here */}  //Line: 28
   ```
8. Now you create again a new instance of: `App` in `PredefinedApp()` same as before (Point 2 - 6, expect in the constructor you have other variable values + you don't enter the loop, since the array is empty)
9. You assign a [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to a class property:

   ```
   $app->cleanup = function($parent){  //Line: 31
       //Do stuff like: echo "I'm saved";
   };
   ```
10. You return the new created object of `App`:

    ```
    return $app;  //Line: 34
    ```
11. Here already the [`__destruct()` gets called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8523433/3933332), because when the function ends the `refcount` goes to 0 of that `zval` and `__destruct()` is triggered. But since `$this->apps` is empty nothing happens here.
12. The new created object in that function gets returned and assigned to the array index (**Note:** We are back from the function to point 6.1):

    ```
    $apps[$name] = $dependName($this);  //Line: 10
    //$apps["App1"] = PredefinedApp($this);
    ```
13. The constructor ends with assigning the local array to the class property:

    ```
    $this->apps = $apps;  //Line: 12
    ```
14. **Now the entire script ends (We have done line: 37)! Which means for the object `$app` the [`__destruct()` is triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8523433/3933332) for the same reason as before for `$app` in the function `PredefinedApp()`**
15. **Which means you now loop through each element from `$this->apps`, which only holds the returned object of the function:**

    ```
    public function __destruct(){  //Line: 15
        foreach($this->apps as $dep){
            $result = $dep->cleanup($this);
        }
    }
    ```

    ```
    Array(
        "App1" => App Object
            (
                [apps:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [name] => PredefinedApp
                [cleanup] => Closure Object
                    (
                        [parameter] => Array
                            (
                                [$parent] => <required>
                            )

                    )

            )
    )
    ```
16. For each element (Here only 1) you execute:

    ```
    $result = $dep->cleanup($this);  //Line: 17
    ```

    [**But you don't call the closure! It tries to call a class method.**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4535330/3933332) So there is no `cleanup` class method, it's just a class property.  Which then means [`__call()` gets invoked](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods):

    ```
    public function __call($name, $arguments){  //Line: 21
        if(is_callable([$this, $name])){
            return call_user_func_array([$this, $name], $arguments);
        }
    }
    ```
17. The `$arguments` contains itself (`$this`). And `is_callable([$this, $name])` is `TRUE`, because `cleanup` is callable as closure.
18. So now we are getting in the endless stuff, because:

    ```
    return call_user_func_array([$this, $name], $arguments);  //Line: 23
    ```

    Is executed, which then looks something like this:

    ```
    return call_user_func_array([$this, "cleanup"], $this);
    ```

    **Which then again tries to call `cleanup` as a method and again `__call()` is invoked and so on...**

So at the end of the entire script the hole disaster starts. But I have some good news, as complicated this sounds, the solution is much simpler!

## Solution

Just change:

```
return call_user_func_array([$this, $name], $arguments);  //Line: 23
```

with this:

```
return call_user_func_array($this->$name, $arguments);
                           //^^^^^^^^^^^ See here
```

Because by changing it like this you don't try to call a method, but the closure. So if you also put:

```
echo "I'm saved";
```

in the closure when you assign it, you will end up with the output:

```
I'm saved
```

Comment: This is a *much* better answer than mine actually describing the cause... however the "fix" is the same. The OP claims he can't call `$this->$name` because `$name` is an object (you have a syntax error in your answer btw).

Comment: This works great too! @doublesharp, when using your code, it for some reason didn't work when transferring it to the actual code, but it worked in the example...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Cleaned my answer up, maybe you want to take a look again, it should be much cleaner

Answer (score 3):

Replacing your `__call()` function with the following will prevent the recursion that you are seeing:

```
public function __call( $method, $arguments ) {
    if ( $this->{$method} instanceof Closure ) {
        return call_user_func_array( $this->{$method}, $arguments );
    } else {
        throw new Exception( "Invalid Function" );
    }
}
```

---

See @Rizier123's answer for more detail, but the TLDR version is:

The problem is that you initial invoke `cleanup()` as a method call with `$dep->cleanup()` which invokes `__call()`. If you then use `call_user_func_array()` and pass `[$this, $method]` it calls it as a method, thus invoking `_call()` again and triggering the loop (and never *actually* calling the `cleanup()` method), whereas using `$this->{$method}` will invoke it as a `Closure` and prevent the looping.

Comment: @Rizier123 Still trying to confirm exactly, but I believe it is because by not checking if it is a Closure it is pushing too many calls onto the stack and running out of memory.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but curious why `cleanup()` is a `Closure` rather than a method on `App`?

Comment: I want to be able to override it in the function, but I couldn't think of a way to do that.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out why, but I was taught to use the `$this->{$method}` format to prevent looping. I believe it has to do with the way `call_user_func_array()` reflects on the object... but not sure. I found this which isn't terribly helpful but does confirm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly

Comment: Updated my answer with some details from @Rizier123.